# Why do porn websies not use HTTPS?

Tags: tls, ethics

It seems that information relating to porn habits is quite telling, why wouldn't porn websites make the effort in protecting them?

Comment: People visit porn websites despite the infuriating and unavoidable advertisements, the blatant malware, the fact that their actors can't act, their set designers routinely phone it in, and their screenwriters don't exist.  And you genuinely believe they're worried about losing viewers because they use one protocol most people are only vaguely aware of over another protocol most people are only vaguely aware of? You overestimate the discriminating and tech-savvy tastes of the modern porn consumer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Porn sites and advertisements are two business models which often depend on getting the best performance with the fewest costs. HTTPS impacts performance during the initial TLS handshake (can be reduced but not eliminated with session resumption). It also needs more computing resources to encrypt the traffic on the server side and decrypt it on the client side, which again impacts performance and/or increases the costs to run the site.

Another problem is the inclusion of third party sites (advertisements etc). To work with a https porn site these resources would need to be https too, because otherwise they will not show up (mixed content error in the browser).

But probably as soon as enough paying customers ask for https they will provide it optionally, because losing traffic because of an unsatisfied customer is probably more significant than losing performance or increasing costs.

Answer (score -1):

Porn sites use HTTPS when you log in to your account (if you have one) but why hinder performance sending free videos over https? the only thing there is to hide is what you are searching for on the porn site.

If you are watching legal porn then who truly cares about the https? the only thing you risk is a MitM attack but not under a great risk.

source: erm a friend? *cough*

Comment: If you are watching legal porn then who truly cares about the https?  Well what porn you like, says a lot about your personality.

Comment: @whatever489 true, but if you are currently getting a MitM attack or someone is sniffing your network websites are still easy to see, and your porn search. well I could find out more information than that with my eyes closed. https is just not a viable option for porn sites unless using credentials. if you are worried about your searches use a freevpn or proxy!